# Typescript function overloading with different first param

Tags: typescript

I have a class that needs to implement a method that accepts two or one params based on the child class.

```
class MyClass { 
    update(obj: HashMap);
    update(id: ID, obj: HashMap);
    update(objOrId: HashMap | ID, obj?: HashMap) {
      console.log('here I want to use only the first param');
    }
}

class SubClass extends MyClass {
    update(id: ID, obj: HashMap) {
      console.log('here I want to use both params');
    }
}
```

The problem is that the SubClass yelling at me that the update signature is not compatible with the base class. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should get the following error:

> Property `'update'` in type `'SubClass'` is not assignable to the same property in base type `'MyClass'`.
>
> Type `'(id: ID, obj: HashMap) => void'` is not assignable to type `'{ (obj: HashMap): any; (id: ID, obj: HashMap): any; }'`.

The reason for this is that when overriding a method, it has to have the *exact same type* as the original method. Since the method in `MyClass` is an overloaded type, it has two alternative types. But the overriden method only has one.

So you *need* to specify the exact same overloads, even if you don’t need them in the subtype:

```
class SubClass extends MyClass {
    update(obj: HashMap);
    update(id: ID, obj: HashMap);
    update(objOrId: HashMap | ID, obj?: HashMap) {
      console.log('here I want to use both params');
    }
}
```

Remember that TypeScript will actually only emit the final function definition, and there is no run-time validation for the parameter types. So you will still have to handle the case that just a `HashMap` will be passed to your `SubClass` instance. This is especially true if you consider the [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) which also requires that any instance of `SubClass` can be used as a `MyClass` instance; so passing just a `HashMap` is absolutely fine.

[Example on TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20HashMap%20%3D%20object%3B%0D%0Atype%20ID%20%3D%20string%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20MyClass%20%7B%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20update(obj%3A%20HashMap)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20update(id%3A%20ID%2C%20obj%3A%20HashMap)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20update(objOrId%3A%20HashMap%20%7C%20ID%2C%20obj%3F%3A%20HashMap)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('here%20I%20want%20to%20use%20only%20the%20first%20param')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20SubClass%20extends%20MyClass%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20update(obj%3A%20HashMap)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20update(id%3A%20ID%2C%20obj%3A%20HashMap)%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20update(objOrId%3A%20HashMap%20%7C%20ID%2C%20obj%3F%3A%20HashMap)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20console.log('here%20I%20want%20to%20use%20both%20params')%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Alet%20sub%20%3D%20new%20SubClass()%3B%0D%0Asub.update(%22foo%22%2C%20%7B%20bar%3A%20'baz'%20%7D)%3B)

Comment: The update method of the subclass still shows the one params approach. I need there the two params approach.

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to say with that. You can totally call the method with two arguments on the subclass. See the linked example.

Comment: I can call them, you are right, but the autocompletion shows always the one value approach

Comment: see the signature of the auto-completion in your live example.

Comment: No, when you type the `sub.update(`, you will get the auto completion pop-up and then you can move the cursor up and down to cycle through the various overloads.

Comment: @undefined This is very specific to your IDE and autocompletion you're using, while the question is about TS in general. As it was said, Typescript playground shows a list of overloads.

Comment: I can't force the two params signature when using the subclass?

Comment: As mentioned in my answer, the subclass’ implementation of `update` is *required* to also accept just one argument as per the substitution principle. Every object of type `SubClass` also has to be a valid `MyClass` object. And if you want to be able to call a `MyClass` object with just one argument, then a `SubClass` object *also* has to allow that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the public overload signatures to your class. The implementation signature is not visible to anyone (not even inside `MyClass`) so the compatibility that is checked is for the public signatures, and since the compiler can't find them it issues an error:

```
class SubClass extends MyClass {
    update(obj: HashMap) : void;
    update(id: ID, obj: HashMap): void;
    update(objOrId: HashMap , obj?: HashMap): void{
    console.log('here I want to use both params');
    }
}
```

Comment: The update method of the subclass still shows the one params approach. I need there the two params approach.